# Game created with ovals, while loops, and for loops

Tags: python, tkinter

I am working on a program that fires a bullet from a cannon after having the user input a degree in order to hit the randomly generated target at its position. The program works fine if you are able to hit the target on the first try every time but it seems if I miss that it creates a new target, like it is supposed to, but does not delete the old one. Any idea on how to correct that?

```
from tkinter import *
import time
import math
import random

master = Tk()

w = Canvas(master, width=800,height=800, bg="white")
w.pack()

#Cannon
Img1 = PhotoImage(file="goldcannon.gif")
Pic1 = w.create_image(85,600, image=Img1)

#Grass
w.create_rectangle(0,645, 800,800, fill="green")
w.update()

Choice = "Yes"
Win = False
while(True):
    if Choice == "No":
        TY = w.create_text(400,400, text="Thank you for playing!", font="arial")
        break
    x = []

    #Cannon Target
    Target_x = 700
    Target_y = random.randrange(100,560)
    Target = w.create_oval(Target_x,Target_y, Target_x+25,Target_y+25, fill="red")


    while(True):
        if Choice == "No":
            break


        #Cannon Degree
        degree = simpledialog.askstring("Cannon Degree", "What is your guess?", \
                                initialvalue="Enter a Degree")

        degree = 90 - int(degree)

        #Cannon Bullet
        bMove = w.create_oval(150,560, 150+10,560+10, fill="black")

        for i in range(90):
            w.move(bMove,math.sin(math.radians(degree))*10, \
                   -math.cos(math.radians(degree))*10)
            time.sleep(0.06)
            w.update()

            x = w.find_overlapping(Target_x-10,Target_y, Target_x+35,Target_y+35)

            if len(x)>1:
                w.delete(bMove)
                Hit = w.create_text(400,400, text="You hit the target!", font="arial")
                Choice = simpledialog.askstring("Hello", "Would you like to play again?", \
                                                initialvalue="Yes or No")
                w.delete(Hit)
                w.delete(Target)

                Win = True

                break

        if Win == True:
            break
```

Comment: To learn how to do animation properly in tk, using the `.after(ms, func, *args)` function, search SO for `[tkinter] root.after`.  As it is, you are essentially recreating what the tk loop does, and for anything more complicated, it will get unwieldy.

Answer (score 0):

The only place I see `w.delete(Target)` is within the 'if hit' block.  You need to add it somewhere else where it will be executed for missed.  I presume that is after the `for` loop, before `if Win == True:`.

Comment: I added the w.delete(Target) right before the  final "if Win == True:" and if I miss the target, it gets deleted :(

Answer (score 0):

i believe ive fixed it for you, heres the code:

```
from tkinter import *
import time
import math
import random

master = Tk()

w = Canvas(master, width=800,height=800, bg="white")
w.pack()

#Cannon
Img1 = PhotoImage(file="cannon.gif")
Pic1 = w.create_image(85,600, image=Img1)

#Grass
w.create_rectangle(0,645, 800,800, fill="green")
w.update()

Choice = "Yes"
Win = False
while(True):
    if Choice == "No":
        TY = w.create_text(400,400, text="Thank you for playing!", font="arial")
        break
    x = []

    #Cannon Target
    Target_x = 700
    Target_y = random.randrange(100,560)
    Target = w.create_oval(Target_x,Target_y, Target_x+25,Target_y+25, fill="red")


    while(True):
        if Choice == "No":
            break


        #Cannon Degree
        degree = simpledialog.askstring("Cannon Degree", "What is your guess?", \
                                initialvalue="Enter a Degree")

        degree = 90 - int(degree)

        #Cannon Bullet
        bMove = w.create_oval(150,560, 150+10,560+10, fill="black")

        for i in range(90):
            w.move(bMove,math.sin(math.radians(degree))*10, \
                   -math.cos(math.radians(degree))*10)
            time.sleep(0.06)
            w.update()

            x = w.find_overlapping(Target_x-10,Target_y, Target_x+35,Target_y+35)

            if len(x)>1:
                w.delete(bMove)
                Hit = w.create_text(400,400, text="You hit the target!", font="arial")
                Choice = simpledialog.askstring("Hello", "Would you like to play again?", \
                                                initialvalue="Yes or No")
                w.delete(Hit)
                w.delete(Target)

                Win = True

                break

        if Win == True:
            w.create_oval(Target_x+30,Target_y+30, Target_x+30,Target_y+30, fill='white')
            Win = False
            print('why hello')
            break
```

hope this works for you, thanks.

Comment: why? i run it on my computer and it seems to be working fine,